# how to use webpack split common business code?

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-2, vue-router

I use webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin to Generate an extra chunk(vueCommon.js) which contains vuejs、vue-router、vue-resource...;but I want to Generate another business commonChunk like util.js。they are used just in some pages by "import ajax from '../service/service.js'";

problems after build:
every generated page.js has the code of service.js。

brief demos:
https://github.com/wxungang/vueJs

```js
//webpack.base.js

"use strict";

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const CONFIG = require('./config');
var projectRoot = CONFIG.projectRoot || path.resolve(__dirname, '../');
var _ENV = CONFIG.env || 'dev';//prod

module.exports = {
    devtool: _ENV != 'prod' ? '#eval-source-map' : false,
    context: __dirname,//http://wxungang.github.io/1104/vue
    entry: {
        app: path.join(projectRoot, './vue/app.js'),
        page: path.join(projectRoot, './vue/page.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(projectRoot, './build/vue-' + _ENV),
        publicPath: '',//'./build/vue-'+_ENV+'/',//path.join(__dirname, '../src/build/dev/')
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: 'chunks/[name].chunk.js',
        // crossOriginLoading: 'anonymous'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
            'vue-router$': 'vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js'
        },
        modules: ["node_modules"],
        mainFiles: ["index", "app"],
        extensions: [".js", ".json", '.vue']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
                        // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
                        // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this nessessary.
                        'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
                        'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
                        'less': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'
                    }
                    // other vue-loader options go here
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'vue-html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        //注入一些全局变量
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            _ENV_: _ENV,
            _VERSION_: JSON.stringify("1.0.0")
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "commons",
            // (the commons chunk name)

            filename: "vueCommons.js",
            // (the filename of the commons chunk)

            // minChunks: 2,
            // (Modules must be shared between 3 entries)

            // chunks: ["pageA", "pageB"],
            // (Only use these entries)
            // children: true,
            // async: true,
        }),
        //可以和entry文件联合配置
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            title: 'vueJs of app',
            filename: 'app.html',
            template: '../vue/entry/template.ejs',
            scripts: ['./vueCommons.js', './app.js']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            title: 'vueJs of page',
            filename: 'page.html',
            template: '../vue/entry/template.ejs',
            scripts: ['./vueCommons.js', './page.js']
        })
    ]

};
```

Comment: Could you provide your `webpack.config.js`? It's difficult to imagine it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you use CommonsChunkPlugin to generate vueCommon.js?

A simple way is to add a new wepack entry like

`utils: ['../service/service.js']`

then add a new CommonsChunkPlugin instance in the webpack plugins array like this

`new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('utils'),`

the CommonsChunkPlugin will do the work by remove all utils module in other chunk files and generate only one utils.js.

Or you can just set minChunks option of the existing CommonsChunkPlugin into a number to wrap the vue file and utils together.